# Unexpected Result With JavaScript Substr()

Tags: javascript, substr

I'm having a problem with substr() in JavaScript. 

Please look at the code below.

> The following works as expected.  **y = 2017**

```
var add_date = "20170505";
var y = add_date.substr(0, 4);
alert(y);
```

> But... the following doesn't work. It should return '05' but instead it returns 0505.  **m = 0505**

```
var add_date = "20170505";
var m = add_date.substr(4, 6);
alert(m);
```

Could someone explain me what's wrong?

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: @exebook What if I didn't know substring existed? 

Comment: Even without knowing `substring` existed, it would have taken a minimal amount of research for you to learn that `substr` didn't work the way you thought it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.substr(4,6)` method returns **6** characters starting at index `4`. Use `.substring` instead.

```js
var add_date = "20170505",
    y = add_date.substring(0, 4);
    console.log(y);


var add_date = "20170505",
    m = add_date.substring(4, 6);
    console.log(m);
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for JavaScript's substr command is: **string.substr(start, length)**. So the line of code should read:

```
var m = add_date.substr(4, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of [`String.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) specifies the number of characters *to extract*.

Your code should look as follows:

```
var add_date = "20170505";
var m = add_date.substr(4, 2);
alert(m);
```

Answer (score 2):

The **[`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** has two arguments that specify a starting index and a length to extract.

You may be confusing it with the **[`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** method that takes two arguments of start index and end index.

Answer (score 1):

## The parameters of the SUBSTR function are start and length, not start and end

In the console you can see this:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKL".substr(0,4)
"ABCD"

"ABCDEFGHIJKL".substr(4,6)
"EFGHIJ"

"ABCDEFGHIJKL".substr(4,2)
"EF"
```

So what you want is

```
.substr(4,2)
```